# yoga 2 pro won't boot after update to ubuntu 15.10/ GDM

Tags: gdm, 15.10

After upgrading to Ubuntu 15.10, my mouse pointer was no longer visible. As a remedy, I installed GDM as suggested in some posts here. That worked, but now (first full boot after installation of gdm) the laptop stopped showing the login screen, showing this instead:
[image]

Edit: using `ctrl-alt-f1`, I am able to enter a terminal and try stuff out in tty1.

Edit2: internet access seems to work too.

Edit3: sudo apt-get updating and upgrading install stuff, but nothing that makes the problem go away.

Edit4: part of some graphical interface *is* loaded, as the Ubuntu shutdown screen is shown on `reboot -n`

Edit5: removing gdm and rebooting got me a new problem with this startup screen message [image]. Here I *can* `ctrl-alt-f1`, log in, and sudo lightdm to enter the graphical interface. However, now I am constantly asked for my password. Not sure why. Also, sound is not working. Any help greatly appreciated.

Edit6: trying to install new kernel didn't solve the problem. Removed gdm and using lightdm instead solved all of the booting problems. But the cursor is still invisible.

At least that's consistent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### step 1

First I reverted to lightdm. If you never installed gdm you can skip this step. This sounds straightforward but it's not, as you need to use gdm to select lightdm as the default before removing gdm. So:

CTRL-ALT-F1

log in

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall gdm`

select lightdm as the default window manager

`sudo apt-get remove gdm`

restart for good measure.

#### step 2

If it doesn't work still:

CTRL-ALT-F1

log in

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-session` (reinstall if you have to)

This
solved it for me.

Why you ask? No idea. Your mileage may vary.

## Update

My mileage did vary, after an update I was back to square one. I noticed some inconsistencies too, so I decided to use

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
```

And it seems to be working again. For now.